# How to display grid view inside fragment in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Here is the piece of code that I have been trying.
The adapter code is below.
Made an array list for storing the data, and want to display it in the fragment using grid view. The app is running but its not showing the grid layout.

```
import android.os.strictmode.WebViewMethodCalledOnWrongThreadViolation
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.BaseAdapter
import android.widget.ImageView
import com.shyptsolution.nitrr.R

class GalleryAdapter(gallerylist:ArrayList<GalleryDataModel>):BaseAdapter() {
    var galleryList=gallerylist
    var image:ImageView?=null
    override fun getCount(): Int {
       return galleryList.size
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        return galleryList[position]
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
       var inflator=LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).inflate(R.layout.gallery_ticket,null)
        image=inflator.findViewById(R.id.gallery)
        image?.setImageResource(galleryList[position].image)
        return inflator
    }
}
```

The code for the fragment is given below

```
package com.shyptsolution.nitrr.gallery

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.GridView
import com.shyptsolution.nitrr.R

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 * Use the [Gallery.newInstance] factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
class Gallery : Fragment() {
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null
    lateinit var adapter:GalleryAdapter
    var gallerygrid=activity?.findViewById<GridView>(R.id.galllerygrid)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        adapter= GalleryAdapter(GalleryData.galleryphoto)
        gallerygrid?.adapter=adapter
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false)
    }

    companion object {
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment Gallery.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            Gallery().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

How can I do it, I have done recycler view in the fragment but couldn't figure out the problem here.

Comment: Have u try using `GridLayoutManager`? https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/GridLayoutManager

Comment: I solved my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the list of changes that  I have made and now its working fine.

```
package com.shyptsolution.nitrr.gallery

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.GridLayout
import android.widget.GridView
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import com.shyptsolution.nitrr.R

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 * Use the [Gallery.newInstance] factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
class Gallery : Fragment() {
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null

    var listofphoto=GalleryData.galleryphoto
  lateinit  var adapter:GalleryAdapter
    var gallerygrid=activity?.findViewById<GridView>(R.id.galllerygrid)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
//        adapter=GalleryAdapter(listofphoto)
//        var galleryview=activity?.findViewById<GridView>(R.id.galllerygrid)
//        galleryview?.adapter=adapter
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
//        adapter= GalleryAdapter(GalleryData.galleryphoto)
//        gallerygrid?.adapter=adapter




        var view:View=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false)
        gallerygrid=view.findViewById(R.id.galllerygrid)
        adapter= GalleryAdapter(listofphoto)
        gallerygrid?.adapter=adapter
        return view
    }

    companion object {
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment Gallery.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            Gallery().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Added the Gallery adapter and then set the grid adapter. Its working fine.